# How to give data to the controller file from a html form?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, view, routes

I am new in node.js and programing in web, and I don't have a simple code to you for test my problem, but I think that the problem could be simple of resolve, I have a view in which I want to send some information to the controller file, here I will put the view and the other files:

view of index.html.js:

```
<form action="ongs">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is the controller of name ongs.js

```
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');
var Koa = require('koa');
const router = new KoaRouter();

var app = new Koa();

router.get('ongs', '/', async (ctx) => {
  const skelevar = "hi skel";
  console.log('\n------ get ------');
  await ctx.render('ongs/index', { skelevar });
});

router.post('/ongs', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log('\n--fafafa');
  ctx.body = ctx.request.body;
  console.log('\n--isisisisisisisisi');
});

console.log('\n hi guys');
module.exports = router;
app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

here is the file routes.js:

```
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');

const hello = require('./routes/hello');
const index = require('./routes/index');
const ongs = require('./routes/ongs');

const router = new KoaRouter();

router.use('/', index.routes());
router.use('/hello', hello.routes());
router.use('/ongs', ongs.routes());

module.exports = router;
```

and the composition of my folder are the following:

[image: the red arrows show the path of each file that i show you]

the red arrows show the depth of each file that i show you

here is what the view show me:
[image]

When I press in submit the page refresh but any of my console log in the router.post are showing in the console.
the only message that I get when I press submit in the console is the following:

```
 ------ get ------
      --> GET /ongs?fname=John&lname=Doe 200 18ms 609b
    ℹ ｢hot｣: WebSocket Client Connected
      <-- GET /assets/app.js
      --> GET /assets/app.js 200 5ms 1.29mb
      <-- GET /assets/logo.png
      --> GET /assets/logo.png 200 3ms 6.77kb
    ℹ ｢hot｣: WebSocket Client Connected
      <-- GET /ongs?fname=John&lname=Doe
    ------ get ------
      --> GET /ongs?fname=John&lname=Doe 200 18ms 609b
      <-- GET /assets/app.js
      <-- GET /assets/logo.png
      --> GET /assets/app.js 200 5ms 1.29mb
      --> GET /assets/logo.png 200 5ms 6.77kb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is getting submitted as a `GET` request which is the default since you're not passing a `method` attribute in the `form` tag. As you can see, the data is sent as a part of the URL and the backend responds with the `ongs/index` view. Pass a `method` attribute of `post` in the form tag to submit the form data as a `POST` request.

```
<form action="/ongs" method="post">
 ...
</form>
```

There's another issue. The above request will fail with a 404 since you don't have a request handler for `POST /ongs` but you do have one for `POST /ongs/ongs`. Update the `POST` endpoint route to be just `/`.

```
router.post('/', (ctx, next) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: this solve part of my problem :D, because now the console show me the following massage,  
  <-- POST /ongs
  --> POST /ongs 404 307ms -
this problem is for the path in the view?

Comment: @mrpepo877 You don't have a `POST /ongs` route but `POST /ongs/ongs`. Looks like you missed the part of my answer to update the POST endpoint route. Just updated my answer with an explanation.